# How to enable tabs on the left panel?

Tags: interface

I am new to Blender and was watching some video tutorials. However, the one in the video (v2.78) has the tabs on the left panel,

[image: tabs]

and mine (v2.69) doesn't.

[image: my screenshot]

How do I enable them and what is their correct name? Or were they added in some later version?

Comment: I think it came in a later version, yeah. Why don't you upgrade it? There's downside, only positives.

Comment: @Leo, any proof of that? Ubuntu 14.04 repositories contain only v2.69. Before I upgrade I would like to make sure it is really necessary.

Comment: As well as upgrading blender, also recommend upgrading to ubuntu 18  (the repos are up to date (for now))  Very impressed after recent upgrade  from 14.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade your Blender. This feature was [introduced in 2.70](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.70/UI). By now 2.79 is the current version. You can just download a tarball, extract it, and run it.